# Could APL be implemented in Scala as a DSL?

Tags: scala, dsl, apl

There is a old computer language called APL. Could this be implemented in Scala as a DSL?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29

Comment: As an external DSL, it obviously could be. As an internal DSL, you run into problems mentioned by @Owen.

Comment: What is an external DSL?

Comment: See http://www.infoq.com/articles/External-DSL-Vaughn-Vernon

Comment: Hey, Phil, did you manage to do that in the end? I am also exploring this very topic right now. For now I am thinking about changing the original APL notation so that it will work. Also I am looking at what about the J language..

Comment: I have not done this, but I think it shouldn't be so difficult to do, since APL is not a complicated language and Scala has access to many Java libraries for array processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone could probably give a better answer than this, but this is my initial thought:

1. A Scala DSL should in theory be able to implement *any* programming language because it could build up an arbitrary structure representing the syntax, and then evaluate that.
2. A Scala DSL could not exactly replicate APL syntax for many reasons, one of which is that

   'single quotes'

can denote a string in APL, but not in Scala. Also (from the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_syntax_and_symbols))

```
×/2 3 4
```

wouldn't be valid Scala.

I don't know how close you could get, though...

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript implementation exists here: https://github.com/ngn/apl